# Can I recover a deleted world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I accidentally deleted my world, is there a way to find the files somewhere on my computer? I have already looked where the files would be if I hadn't deleted the world.

I am using a Mac but is not 100% mine so i cant do anything too crazy.

Comment: deleting a world does (in essence) a `rm -rf` on the world save folder

Comment: there is a specific way to recover a deleted world, without using these programs. i dont remember how but i did it a few years ago

Answer (score 6):

A deleted file on your harddrive may be recovered using file recovery programs, given that there hasn't been written too much to the disk afterwards. However, there are no guarantees.

MAC has several alternatives, however I haven't tried them. [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard](http://www.easeus.com/mac/mac-undelete-free/) is one example.

Sidenote: For PC-users there's (for instance) [Piriform's Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) you could try to use.

Comment: Or for PC, if you don't mind losing a few things, and don't like downloading things, you could simple recover your PC to a date very close behind (Not sure about Apple products though...), but be sure to back everything up first.

Comment: All the listed programs are Windows applications

Comment: Ramhound: If you read the answer, there are MAC and PC alternatives provided.

Answer (score 2):

If the key operator of the machine had the foresight to enable Time Machine, that could be used to recover the files.